# Write to Linked server Destination connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package. I read data from flat files and then stage that data on SQL1. I then modify that data and insert the New data into a table on a linked server (SQL2.db1.Table1). I can connect to the databse connection created in SSIS and see the columns in Table1.

I created a new SQL Account (Not AD) Credential and Proxy for the SSIS Job agent (SQLDO).
I have set the (SQLDO) Credential to map to the sa account on SQL2 and have given datareader and datawriter to the tables needed for the package on SQL1 and SQL2 and added Table1 and msdb through User Mapping on SQL2.
ON SQL2 Table1 security I have added datareader and datawriter memberships to (SQLDO)

I am not sure if my permissions are correct. I can run the package from VS2017 and it will run fine but when I deploy it, it fails.

This is a start can someone help

Comment: Check your protection level. Your password is likely being wiped on deployment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/security/access-control-for-sensitive-data-in-packages?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I am not using a saved password for the connection. I am using Windows Auth and running as SQL Server Agent account through a job.